# JavaScript form validation with PHP not sending emails

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I have a contact form that uses JavaScript validation for the fields but when I link the form to my PHP, it doesn't send the email. It would greatly appreciated if someone could help me with this. I'm not too familiar with PHP and how it interacts with other languages.

Here's a [live demo](http://rickeyan.com/website_test/form/form.html).

Here's the code:

****EDIT****

**CURRENT JAVASCRIPT:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
reEmail = /^[\w-|+|'|]+(\.[\w-|+|'|]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(:\d{4})?$/

function myFunction()
{
var y;
y = document.getElementById('name');
var x;
x = document.getElementById('email');
var z;
z = document.getElementById('message');
var e;
e = 0;


if(y.value == "Full Name*"){
     alert("Full Name Required");
     e = e + 1
     return false;
} 

if(!(reEmail.test(x.value))){
     alert("E-Mail Invalid");
     e = e + 1
     return false;
} 

if(z.value == "Your Message*"){
    alert("Please write a message.");
    e = e + 1;
    return false;
}

if(e < 0){
    return false;   
} else {
    alert("Thank you. Your message has been sent!");
    return true;
}

}

</script>
```

****EDIT****

**CURRENT HTML:**

```
<body>
<div class="form" align="center">
<form onSubmit="myFunction();" name="contact" action="sendform.php" method="post" >
    <span style="display:block;">
        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" class="txt" maxlength="50" value="Full Name*" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
    </span>
        <br />
    <span style="display:block">
        <input name="email" type="text" id="email" class="txt" maxlength="20" value="Your E-Mail*" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" >
    </span>
        <br />
    <span style="display:block">
        <textarea name="message" type="text" id="message" class="txt" maxlength="500" value="Your Message*" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">Your Message*</textarea>
    </span>
        </form>
        <br />
    <span id="required">* Indicates Required Fields</span>
            <br />
    <input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" class="submit" value="Submit" >

</div>
</body>
```

**PHP(sendform.php):**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "email@domain.com";
$email_subject = "Your email subject line";


function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['message'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}

$first_name = $_POST['name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$comments = $_POST['message']; // required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: First remove `@` from the mail function

Comment: I advice you not to use @ at all. Make all needed checks, log all errors, etc. Then you will be able to analyze why something is not working.

Comment: Second, don't assume the mail function is successful. Always check the result and show a message accordingly.

Comment: i removed the @ before the menu function but that didn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems is not in your PHP it is in your HTML And Javascript because the page is not reloading:

HTML:

I think it is better to write:

```
<form onSubmit="MyFunction();" name="contact" action="sendform.php" method="post" >
```

Because when you use it like this it reduce the error of writing `MyFunction()` instead instead of `return MyFunction()`in the `onClick` Listener of the submit button

JavaScript:

You have written `var e` , `var y` , `var z` , `var x` without `;`.

When you have checked if `z.value == 'requiredfield'` you have written the return false before the `}`.

And `e` is never incrementing because you have `return false;` before the incremention what prevent it from incrementing.

If you fixed those bugs and tried the code , the page refresh and the email is not delivered then reply in a comment and I will be glad to help You.

EDIT:

Now I know the problem after those fixes the submit button is not a part of form as you close the form and then add the submit so just move the submit button up to before the `</form>`

Comment: I put the "return false;" after "e = e + 1" and before the semi-colons. I also added semi-colons after each declared variable. I also put the onSubmit="myFunction();" in the form tag instead of the submit. When i click submit in the form nothing happens anymore, not even the alert. Any idea what's going on? Sorry for the lack of knowledge here.

Comment: I realized that when I change the onClick="myFunction();" in the submit button to the onSubmit="myFunction();" in the form tag the script doesn't execute.

Comment: @ran913 main it is the solution i have changed this in google chrome console and it works perfectly :D i am glad to help

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
if(z.value == "Your Message*"){
    alert("Please write a message.");
    return false;
    e = e + 1
} else if(z.value == "Required Field"){ 
    z.value = "Required Field"
    e = e + 1
} return false;
```

Since you have that `return false;` *after* the closing brace, your code is always stopping when it gets to that point.

Also, whether you return false after incrementing e is not consistent; sometimes you return false, sometimes you don't, and when you do, you return false *before* incrementing e, in which case e doesn't actually get changed. You should be always doing the same thing here.

Also, in your html:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" class="submit" value="Submit" >
```

The `onclick` should be `return myFunction()`, or else the form submission will always happen regardless of the outcome of your javascript function.

Comment: I rewrote my js to look like this, but no such luck when trying to send an email. Am I doing anything wrong?
if(y.value == "Full Name*"){
   alert("Full Name Required");
   e = e + 1
   return false;
 } 
 
 if(!(reEmail.test(x.value))){
   alert("E-Mail Invalid");
   e = e + 1
   return false;
 } 
 
 if(z.value == "Your Message*"){
  alert("Please write a message.");
  e = e + 1;
  return false;
 }
 
 if(e > 0){
  return false; 
 } else {
  alert("Thank you. Your message has been sent!");
  return true;
 }

Comment: If it's not the javascript, then it has to be the php. Remove the @ and see if you get any errors. If you don't, then it's possible your webhost has disabled php's mail() function, and you'll have to use sendmail instead.

Comment: Incidentally, in your current javascript you have `if(e < 0){` - that will always return false. I think you meant `if(e > 0){`

Answer (score 0):

As i think it's because of it:

```
if(e > 0){
    return false;   
} else {
    alert("Thank you. Your message has been sent!");
    return true;
}
}
```

u add 1 to e every time the validation passes and it will be always greater than 0, i dont know if its ur mistake but i thik it should be like

```
if(e != 5){
        return false;   
    } else {
        alert("Thank you. Your message has been sent!");
        return true;
    }
    }
```

Why 5? Because u add 1 to e 5 times so at the end it should stay with 5.